# Make CSV Data to String List Python

Tags: python, csv

I have CSV file with data like this =

```
'01,02,VM001,02,21,0ffadb' 
'01,02,VM001,02,21,0aadbcd'
'01,02,VM001,02,21,012adbc'
```

I want make into string like this :

```
"['01,02,VM001,02,21,0aadbcd'], ['01,02,VM001,02,21,0aadbcd'],['01,02,VM001,02,21,012adbc']"
```

My code like this:

```
datalist = " ".join(map(str,data)).replace ("'","")
```

data is list that get from read CSv file. But I get like this :

```
"[01,02,VM001,02,21,0aadbcd], 
[01,02,VM001,02,21,0aadbcd],
[01,02,VM001,02,21,012adbc]"
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If the data in your CSV file is row based

```
with open(filename, 'r') as input_file:
    datalist = []
    for line in input_file:
        datalist.append(line.strip().split(','))
```

will read in each line at a time, and strip whitespace and new line characters, and split it based on your comma delimiter.

Comment: If you're getting that error, you must be altering `line` before trying to strip it as it will be a string as returned by the file iterator. Are you trying to split before strip ?